# How to safely compare a ssize_t with a int64_t

Tags: c++

I want to safely compare a `ssize_t` variable with `int64_t` variable to check if the values are equal. By safe I mean the comparison should work for any value of `ssize_t`. My first guess is to use a `static_cast` to convert the `ssize_t` to `int64_t` but I'm not sure if it is a safe way to convert?

Something like:

```
ssize_t a = read(...);
int64_t b = getsize(...);
if(static_cast<int64_t>(a) == b){
  // ... read succeeded
} else{
  // ... partial or read failure
}
```

Update: On Ubuntu, they both are of exactly the same size

Comment: Please don't repost the same question again. If your previous question was closed, improve it until it's reopened. Each edit you make will push it back onto the front page, for new eyes to see.

Comment: I was not aware of that, thanks. I already deleted the question, but posted this improved one

Comment: Is portability a concern? ssize_t is usually 64 bits on a 64bits Linux but there's no guaranty whatsoever it can't be smaller of bigger depending on the system

Comment: Put a `static_assert( sizeof(ssize_t) <= sizeof(int64_t) )` anywhere and then just use `a == b`, the compiler will do the rest.  If the `static_assert` fails then `ssize_t` can hold values that cannot be represented in a `int64_t` and nothing can fix that.

Comment: @Tzig it's very unlikey though that `ssize_t` is bigger than `_int64_t`, I'm not aware of any system where that's the case. But on a 32 bit system `ssize_t` is definitely smaller than `int64_t`.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I don't know of any system with size_t>64bits either, it could happen though, if portability and maintainability on the very long term is an issue that's something to be aware of

Comment: @Tzig yes, theroretically it could happen, however with a 64 bit ssize_t you already can address the modest quantity of ~9 Exabytes, so I doubt we'll see 128bit `ssize_t` anytime soon.

Comment: @Jabberwocky we might see it. say if mem address length is 8 bytes then max size is 8 bytes also.  And say eth blockchain address is 20-bytes long haha.

Comment: really for 8 byte address max size wideness is 65-bit but doesn't matter

Comment: @rohitt so what a reason you have to not making both vars `ssize_t` ?

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин I use a function that returns a ssize_t and another that returns an int64_t. I need to test if both return sizes that are equal. I would much so not think about casting into different types, but I just needed to make sure it would not cause any trouble in perhaps a system that uses different sizes.

Comment: @rohitt so you have 32-bit machine and one of functions returns 64-bit value that looks like `ssize_t` one. this means  you need 32-bit edition of this function , not comparison or casting stuff

Answer (score 5):

Don't over-complicate things.

`ssize_t` and `int64_t` are both signed types, thus the common type is the bigger of the two, meaning the conversion is value-preserving.
In conclusion, directly using the comparison-operator will *do the right thing*.

You only have to take care when mixing signed and unsigned, with the unsigned being at least as big as `int` and the signed type. Because only in that case conversion to the common type won't be value-preserving for negative values.
In that case, C++20 helps with [intcmp](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/intcmp)

Comment: but you all miss one detail. if you have to compare var of some type with `size_t` var then you can't make former `size_t` too for some reason. That means you need too know whatever type of this first var is wider than `size_t` or not. no other way. with c++20 or 25 you'll need to do this check

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин Why would I *manually* cast either, instead of letting the compiler figure out the common type and use the appropriate operator and implicit conversions?

Comment: that that you're going to compare  `size_t` var with a var of another type is not good already. so you have a reason for this and can't avoid it.  this comparison means thtat you wanna use non-size_t  var where you should use `size_t` one. In this situation you at least need to know what `size_t` is .on this OS.

Comment: dealing with  `intcmp` here means that you just drop the case

Answer (score 3):

In C++20 you don't even need to care about signness or the size of the operands, just use [intcmp](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/intcmp) to do the comparison

```
if (std::cmp_equal(a, b)) {
  // ... read succeeded
} else{
  // ... partial or read failure
}
```

There's also [`std::in_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/in_range) to check values regardless of type and signness

Comment: it's about sizes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68481775/how-to-safely-compare-a-ssize-t-with-a-int64-t/68481890#comment121028420_68481890

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин the question is `if the values are equal`

Answer (score -4):

most of the time you don't have `ssize_t`. and when you do what stops you from doing

```cpp
int64_t a;
ssize_t b;
b = sizeof(ssize_t) == sizeof(int64_t) ? a : whatever_else;
```

Comment: Could the test be `<=` ?

Comment: @RichardCritten Yes it can (and should) be.

Comment: I dont see how does this answers the question. OP is asking for comparing the values, not assign one to the other

Comment: "... safely compare... i mean the comparison..." nowhere the question mentions assignment. Suppose `a = 1;` and `b = 0;` and `ssize_t`  and `int64_t` are of same size then your code results in `a == b`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number "variable to check if the sizes are equal"

Comment: I think you didnt understand the question, and honestly, a personal attack doesnt make me want to care about this answer

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68481775/how-to-safely-compare-a-ssize-t-with-a-int64-t/68481890#comment121028345_68481775     `==` is more than enough here

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин What if `sizeof(ssize_t)` is smaller than `sizeof(int64_t)`? Converting from a smaller to a larger type is "safe". Why disallow it?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude so you'll catch it with `==`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I believe they think the question is about "safely" comparing `sizeof(int64_t)` with `sizeof(ssize_t)`. Actually the quesiton has a little opportunity for misunderstanding when it says "...to check if the sizes are equal.", I suppose "sizes" refers to `a` and `b`, while it can be misread as "sizes of the types". Anyhow the code in the question is actually quite clear

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number where are you came from dude tell me. in this kind of types `sizeof(a) == sizeof(type_of_a)` always

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number That's my interpretation as well, that `a` and `b` are some sizes that needs to be compared for equality.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number honestly i'll miss nothing  say if you just delete all your comments